# Hibernate when lid is closed laptop 14.04

Tags: 14.04, power-management, hibernate

I need to hibernate the laptop when the lid is closed. Currently there is only suspend option is available.

[image]

Comment: Do this http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/ and the option will appear.

Comment: @Pilot6 : thanks for the link, but no success. still not hibernating when lid is closed

Comment: There must be the option "hibernate" on lid close. Is it enabled?

Comment: @Pilot6 : still there is only suspend mode

Comment: I see. Did you do HandleLidSwitch=hibernate?

Comment: yes....................... `#HandleLidSwitch=suspend` to `HandleLidSwitch=hibernate`

Answer (score 0):

The `pm-is-supported` command (see `man pm-is-supported`) will tell you which suspend/hibernate modes are supported by your hardware. Do this:

```
for i in suspend hibernate suspend-hybrid ; do 
    echo -ne "$i\t"
    pm-is-supported --$i
    [[ $? -eq 0 ]] || echo "Not Supported" && echo "Supported"
done
```

If `pm-is-supported --hibernate` returns a status (in `$?`) of 1, your hardware does NOT support hibernation.

Comment: hibernation is working... but I want to hibernate it when lid is closed.... there is no option for that

Comment: got output as `suspend Supported
hibernate Supported
suspend-hybrid Supported
`